# Iterator function in my LinkedList implementation of a Map is not working

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I have a class `ListMap<K, V>` which has a nested class `ListMapEntry` that implements a class `Entry<K, V>`. In `ListMap`, I have created a list in the form of `LinkedList<Entry<K, V>` which imitates a map. I have created `size()`, `isEmpty()`, `find(K k)`, `get(K k)`, `put(K k, V v)` and `remove(K k)` functions.

I am now attempting to write a `toString()` function that iterates through the map and prints it in the form of: `N : ('key1', 'value1') ('key2','value2') ... ('keyN', 'valueN')`

To do so, I have been given the following functions:

```
@Override
public Iterator<K> keys() {
    return new Iterator<K>() {
        Iterator<Entry<K,V>> iterator = list.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public K next() {
            return iterator.next().key();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public Iterator<V> values() {
    return new Iterator<V>() {
        Iterator<Entry<K,V>> iterator = list.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public V next() {
            return iterator.next().value();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> entries() {
    return list.iterator();
}
```

Here is my `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = this.size() + ": ";
    Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator = this.entries();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        output += "(" + iterator.next().key() + ", " + iterator.next().value() + ") ";
    }

    return output;
}
```

It is returning just the size and semi-colon, followed by nothing else. Where have I gone wrong in using the iterator function to add each element of the map to the `output` string?

**EDIT**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/hsxBcWZv) is the entire `ListMap` class.

I have changed my `toString()` method to the following, which produces the same result:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = this.size() + ": ";
    Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator = this.entries();

    if (iterator == null) {
        return output;
    }
    else {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K, V> entry = iterator.next();
            output += "(" + entry.value().toString() + ", " + entry.key().toString() + ") ";
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're calling `next()` twice in your loop. But beyond that, we could really do with seeing this as a [mcve].

Comment: You are not entering in your while loop, check if this.entries() returns something. and as @JonSkeet mentioned you are making next calls twice in your loop be carefull...

Comment: To get no additional output at all you must have `iterator.hasNext()` returning `false`, i.e. the list is empty.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, OK that makes sense - but if I put a few entries in the list and print the map, it shows the correct size (`list.size()`), but still no elements?

Comment: @JonSkeet i have added the entire class to my post, but not the interfaces etc.

Comment: That's now longer than required. Bear in mind that `toString()` doesn't call `keys()` or `values()`, so that's irrelevant - likewise you don't need `remove` to demonstrate the problem, etc. Again, please post (in the question) a [mcve].